# Eli thought Hannah was drunk

Tags: 1-samuel, context

In 1 Samuel 1:13 (NASB)

> As for Hannah, she was speaking in her heart, only her lips were quivering, but her voice was not heard. **So Eli thought that she was drunk**.

What does this reveal us? (Context, character, mental state, ...)

Comment: From this alone, not a great deal is revealed, other than the fact that maybe not many women prayed like that at the time. There was a lack of devotion at the time. But far more is revealed in Eli's attitude towards his own sons and their shocking behaviour. (Up-voted +1.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll attempt a bit of character analysis. First of all, Eli was the high priest. His words carried awesome authority. More than any other Israelites, Eli represented God. He should have been more careful with the words that came out of his mouth.
Imagine your pastor incorrectly accuses you of wrongdoing while your heart is breaking.

Let's see the context:

> 1 Samuel 1:7 This went on year after year. Whenever Hannah went up to the house of the Lord, her rival provoked her till she **wept** and would **not eat**. 8 Her husband Elkanah would say to her, “Hannah, why are you weeping? Why don’t you eat? Why are you **downhearted**? Don’t I mean more to you than ten sons?”

Contrasting with Eli's action later on, Elkanah was an understanding, sympathetic husband.

> 9Once when they had **finished** eating and **drinking** in Shiloh, Hannah stood up. Now Eli the priest was sitting on his chair by the doorpost of the Lord’s house. 10In her **deep anguish** Hannah prayed to the Lord, **weeping bitterly**. 11And she made a vow, saying, “Lord Almighty, if you will only look on your servant’s misery and remember me, and not forget your servant but give her a son, then I will give him to the Lord for all the days of his life, and no razor will ever be used on his head.”

Hannah was in emotionally deep distress. Tears were in her eyes. What did Eli do. He focused on her lips.

> 12 As she kept on praying to the Lord, Eli observed her **mouth**. 13Hannah was praying in her heart, and her **lips** were moving but her voice was not heard. Eli thought she was **drunk**

Eli completely missed the big picture of her distress and jumped to the wrong conclusion. She was not holding a glass of drink. She had already finished eating and drinking. Eli was quick to order her:

> 14 and said to her, “How long are you going to stay drunk? Put away your wine.”

I do not think that we should excuse Eli's action here. He missed the obvious signs and was quick to think negatively about Hannah. This is his major flaw as the high priest: he was too quick to judge. He completely missed the boat.

> 15“Not so, my lord,” Hannah replied, “I am a woman who is deeply troubled. **I have not been drinking wine or beer**; I was pouring out my soul to the Lord. 16Do not take your servant for a wicked woman; I have been praying here out of my great anguish and grief.”

There was a redeeming aspect about Eli. He was also quick to change course once he recognized his wrong.

> 17Eli answered, “Go in **peace**, and may the God of Israel **grant** you what you have asked of him.”

No hard feelings for Eli or Hannah.

> 18 She said, “May your servant find favor in your eyes.” Then she went her way and ate something, and her face was **no longer downcast**.

The episode ended on a positive note. Praise God!

What does this reveal me?

At this stage of his life, Eli was too quick to judge the innocent. He was not competent to be a high priest.

Comment: «Eli was too quick to judge the innocent. He was not competent to be a high priest.», perhaps in his old age only?

Comment: Sorry, I do not know.

Comment: Só would you like to adjust to accommodate that possibility?

Comment: Right. I adjusted.

Answer (score 3):

What does 1 Samuel 1:13 reveal to us **about Eli?**

> "Now [Hannah] was praying in her heart; only her lips moved, but her voice could not be heard. So Eli thought she was drunk." ( וְחַנָּ֗ה הִ֚יא מְדַבֶּ֣רֶת עַל־לִבָּ֔הּ רַ֚ק שְׂפָתֶ֣יהָ נָּע֔וֹת וְקוֹלָ֖הּ לֹ֣א יִשָּׁמֵ֑עַ וַיַּחְשְׁבֶ֥הָ עֵלִ֖י לְשִׁכֹּרָֽה )

Regarding Eli's thoughts about Channah during **1 שְׁמוּאֵ֕ל Shmuel** [chapter 1, verse 13]:

1. "[She] was-drunk" | **שִׁכֹּרָֽה Shikrah**.
2. "Hannah" | **חַנָּ֗ה Channah** appeared to be babbling silently - "only her lips moved" | **רַ֚ק שְׂפָתֶ֣יהָ נָּע֔וֹת Raq Sfateiha Na'ot**.

What do the statements about Channah in **1 Shmuel 1:13** say about **עֵלִ֖י Eli**?

[A.] Yisraelites traditionally did not pray silently in שִׁלֹ֑ה Shiloh, so Eli thought Channah was drunk.

[B.] Channah possibly was swaying while her lips moved sliently, so Eli thought Channah was drunk.

[C.] Other members of Channah's party were visibly inebriated in [1 Shmuel 1:9] "after they had eaten and drunk at Shiloh" ( וַתָּ֣קָם חַנָּ֔ה אַחֲרֵ֛י אָכְלָ֥ה בְשִׁלֹ֖ה ), so Eli thought Channah was drunk.

Comment: Oh right so one could say that Eli was still in good judgement, in that moment, despite his old age?

Comment: It seems so, he quickly reconsidered his initial judgement based on the situation after Hannah's explanation. (v.17) and even blessed her saying *"Go in peace, and may the God of Israel grant you what you have asked of Him"*.